# Sending Mail to 2 mail id in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, system.net.mail

I have a user registration Form. If a new User register their account in that account. I need to send a message a new user has been registered to my company mail-id and also client mail-id. Now i do it for a single mail-id.  How can I do it for 2 mail-ids?

Comment: **Never** send a password by email.

Comment: **Never** store or log readable passwords, anywhere.

Comment: But that is my client Requirement, I need to do that

Comment: Tell your clients that they are wrong.  Remind them about what happened to Sony and LinkedIn.  **Do not listen to them**, or your name will be associated with the resulting disaster.

Comment: Then at least educate your client about the implications of implementing such a insecure, stupid, naive design. If they do not understand, then please bail out and don't encourage crap design.

Comment: Thank you @SLaks and Magnus for the lecture on security; but that didn't solve the problem. The baseline of the question is "How can I send the same email to two different email addresses", or am I wrong? Can you post some of the code you have so far?

Comment: @KBoek Thanks for your lecture and insight. The ability to send to multiple recipients is very trivial in the .NET framework and the MailMessage() object. Out of pure principle, I will not post code that encourage bad insecure design.

Comment: Don't forget to at least salt the passwords!

Comment: +1.. ok sure. i will explain those issues to my client.

Comment: @ Magnus,@SLaks,@IrishChieftain yeah sure. i will explain those issues to my client. but can u post me how to send a message to two mail id. i wont send user information and their password to my client and also others, but i need to send a message a new user has been registered into your account. So please provide solution for that.

Comment: Now that you have changed the **question** (I've a bad feeling that the adjusted question scope != the intended design), you have an adequate answer posted already.

Comment: yeah i changed my question scope. my only need to send two mail, so for i have been changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

mail.To.Add("first address");
mail.To.Add("second address");
```